# Error with Batik, when converting a SVG: The attribute "xlink:href" of the element <use> is required

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have a SVG file, structured like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="506px" height="261px" viewBox="0 0 506 261" style="overflow: hidden; display: block; width: 506px; height: 261px;">
   <defs>
      <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 5,-5 L 0,0 L 5,5" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="ygc10_0" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 5,-5 L 0,0 L 5,5" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="ygc10_1" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 5,-5 L 0,0 L 5,5" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="ygc10_2" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 5,-5 L 0,0 L 5,5" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="ygc10_3" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 5,-5 L 0,0 L 5,5" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="ygc10_4" />
   </defs>
   <g style="pointer-events:visiblePainted" transform="translate(-57.822952932363535 -41.05614567526554)" image-rendering="auto" shape-rendering="auto">
      <g>
         <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 257.9119715596548,73.05614567526554 L 257.9119715596548,135.06828972638465" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
         <use href="#ygc10_0" transform="matrix(0 -2 2 0 257.912 135.068)" style="pointer-events: none;" />
      </g>
      <g>
         <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(211,211,211)" d="M 107.82295293236353,207.4377203121161 L 107.82295293236353,261.03014731718906" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
         <use href="#ygc10_1" transform="matrix(0 -2 2 0 107.823 261.03)" style="pointer-events: none;" />
      </g>
...
```

And I am trying to generate a PNG from its `ByteArrayInputStream`, like this (please, don't consider the lack of exceptions' handling for now):

```
static ByteArrayOutputStream svgToPng(ByteArrayInputStream streamBytes) throws TranscoderException, IOException {
    PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();

    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(streamBytes);
    ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

    t.transcode(input, output);

    ostream.flush();
    return ostream;
}
```

However, I get the Exception on the `transcode()`'s invocation:

```
org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1
The attribute "xlink:href" of the element <use> is required
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGUseElementBridge.buildCompositeGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGUseElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(Unknown Source)
...
```

Can you please help me? I also try, after my `PNGTranscoder` declaration:

```
t.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI,
                SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
```

But with no effect. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SVG file is invalid, one way to fix it would be to add an xmlns:xlink attribute on the root SVG element like so...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="506px" height="261px" viewBox="0 0 506 261">
```

As [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) points out you also need to change the href attributes to xlink:href as href is SVG 2 and Batik does not support that yet.

Comment: @Andrea And update your `<use>` elements also. Change `href="..."` to `xlink:href="..."`.  The `xlink:` part only became optional in SVG2, and Batik doesn't support SVG2 yet.

Comment: Thank you, Robert and Paul. For now, I've been able to try Robert's advice. I got another error ("Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence
"), I think I need to investigate the Charset originally used. By the way, I'll change soon all those <use>s too. Thank you so much for now.

Comment: Thank you so much again to both of you. Adding the xlink and the SVG-compliance fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

INFO : In my case generate SVG string was not having width value. So it was throwing exception.

```
<g transform="translate(�, 85.00)  scale(�)">
```

It should be like

```
<g transform="translate(168.88, 85.00)  scale(0.36)">
```